# Speed of Nsolve

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve a set of equations.
There is about 1000 variables and 1000 polynomials. Since this is a polynomial and the number of variables and equations are the same, it is solvable. But I'm trying do an effective computation. Would Nsolve be Okay? But it seems that its running time is too long. Would there be a better method instead of Nsolve?

Comment: It will be much better for gathering potential answers if you posted a minimum working example (MWE). NSolve is likely to be the quickest route for such task, in a general sense—but nothing can be said for sure without some form of MWE.

Comment: aha I see...I'll post it after I do some more test...but thanks for the comment. I needed to know whether or not Nsolve is effective in the general sense.

Comment: Unless the system is very close to linear, you will have a better chance with `FindRoot`.

Comment: Yes that is beginning to be clear to me....I did some testing on 25eq.25 variables... and computing time blows up. If it is very linear, then Nsolve would be okay I guess but do you have any other suggestions in Solving large set of linear equations?